# Regex Javascript escape special characters plus characters limit

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with this regex? I need something which allow:
0-9 a-z A-Z
spaces commas hyphens apostrophes and these other special characters: _@=.`
plus at the same time set characters limit into it.

I've got this now but it's throwing invalid regular expression exception.

```
var regex = /^\s*([0-9a-zA-Z\s\,\-\(\)\'\_\@\~\&\*\=\.\`]{1,35}+)\s*$/;
        return this.optional(element) || value.match(regex);
       }, "Please enter a valid name"    );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `{1,35}+` Whats this expected to do? Either the one, or the other. Both together doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: sorry, im new to regex .. i added {1,35} thinking that it will help to validate the character limit (minimum 1 and max 35 characters)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. But then adding `+` which means _one or more_ is pointless.

Comment: @tkausl Plus sign in this context doesn't mean _one or more_. It changes the previous quantifier to _possessive_. Check [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Comment: i see, i didn't know that the `+` sign means so initially, thanks for the help! it works perfectly now :)

Comment: @EganWolf alright, didn't know this one. Seems like JS doesn't support it though as it works (compiles) without the `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `+` after `{1,35}` and escape only special characters:

```js
var regex = /^\s*([0-9a-zA-Z\s,\-()'_@~&*=.`]{1,35})\s*$/;

console.log(regex.test(" asdfghjkl "))
console.log(regex.test(" asdf'&@() "))
console.log(regex.test(" asdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjklasdfghjkl "))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Anything Meta Sequence Combo

It looks like you want anything. If so use:

> ```
> /[\S\s]{1,35}/g
> ```

The brackets `[`...`]` means one character within it is a match.

`\s` is any space.

`\S` is any non-space.

and `{1,35}` means one to thirty-five consecutive matches of whatever preceded it.

### Demo

**Features the way to get the first 1 to 35 characters and also every 1 to 35 characters**

```js
var str = `1234567~!@#$%^&*e()_+_{}{:>><rthjokyuym.,iul[.<>LOI*&^%$#@!@#$%^&*()_+_{}{:>><KJHBGNJMKL>|}{POIUY~!@#$%^&*(+_)O(IU`;

var rgx = /[\s\S]{1,35}/g;

var res = rgx.exec(str);

console.log(`==== The first 35 characters ===========================`);
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(' ');
console.log(`==== OR for every 1 to 35 characters ===================`);
while (res !== null) {
  console.log(res[0]);
  var res = rgx.exec(str);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

div div div.as-console-row:first-of-type,
div div div.as-console-row:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: tomato
}
```